# jQuery appends only if the div isn't empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div element and I want to append an icon to it on hover but jQuery appends the icon only if the div isn't empty else nothing happens.

```js
$('div #tags').hover(function() {
  $(this).append('<p>+</p>')
}, function() {
  $(this).find("p").last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags">
  <p>The div isn't empty</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you just mean `$('#tags')`? `$('div #tags')` selects an element with the ID of `tags` that's a descendant of a div, but that's not the HTML you posted.

Comment: Unclear what you are saying. Are you saying it does not work if that <P> element is not there?

Comment: You should probably be using CSS for this, but also what the other people are saying

Comment: @j08691 With only `$('#tags')` it doesn't work even if the div has elements inside.

Comment: Do you have font awesome referenced?

Comment: @epascarello Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the *div* and the *id* refers to the same element, you should not have any space in the selector in between them.

**Please Note:** Since the [***id***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute is unique in a document, simply `$('#tags')` is safe enough to target the element.

```js
$('#tags').hover(function() {
  $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle ml-1 add-tag-icon"></i>')
}, function() {
  $(this).find("i").last().remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags">
    <p>The div isn't empty</p>
</div>
```

***jQuery appends the icon only if the div isn't empty else nothing happens.***

If  the div is empty there is nothing in the page on which you can hover. Please see the following example:

```js
$('#tags').hover(function() {
  $(this).append('<p>+</p>')
}, function() {
  $(this).find("p").last().remove();
});
```

```css
#tags{
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags">
  
</div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that `div#tags` doesn't provide any benefit over `#tags`. It's slightly higher in terms of CSS precedence but that would only matter if there was another element on the page with the `id` of `tags` too (which shouldn't be the case since `id`s should be unique).

Comment: This appears to be a typo on the part of the OP, which is typically something we close a question for...

Comment: With only $('#tags') it doesn't work even if the div has elements inside.

Comment: @alex3025, because of the uniqueness of the *id* attribute `div#tags` and `#tags` is basically the same thing. There should not be any differences in there behavior:)

Comment: @alex3025, did you notice the update in the answer?

Comment: @Mamun yeah, but with some work I get this working by myself

Answer (score 1):

`$('div #tags')` is a wrong selecting for your `<div>` in your case. What you did means that *jQuery* is looking for an element with the id of `#tags` inside the `<div>`. Instead, you need to make it `$('#tags')`.

Comment: Without `$('div #tags')` it doesn't append even if the div isn't empty

Answer (score 0):

Height & width of `<div>` & `<p>` elements are by default 0, hence your hover effect wouldn't produce(you cannot hover on element):

```
<div id="tags"><p></p></div>
```

If you write some text inside element then width and height will change & you will able to produce hover effect:

```
<div id="tags"><p>Not empty</p></div>
```

Therefore `<i>` doesn't append if `div` or `p` elements are empty